# Pod install warning : is a member of multiple groups

Tags: ios, localization, cocoapods, xib, podspec

**Motive** : Create a library with localised xibs.

What I changed my Podspec to :

```
  s.name         = "MyLibrary"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "A short description of MyLibrary."
  s.license      = "MIT (example)"

  s.author             = { "" => "" }
  s.source_files  = "MyLibrary", "MyLibrary/**/*.{h,m,mm,cpp}"
  s.exclude_files = "Classes/Exclude"

  s.resources = "MyLibrary/**/**/*.{png, lproj}"

  #CHANGE THAT MADE ================>
  s.ios.resource_bundle = { 'CamerCaptureLibBundle-iOS' => ['**/**/*.lproj'] }

  s.dependency "OpenCV", "~> 2.4.9.1"
  s.dependency 'FrameAccessor'

end
```

Following the guidance of this link - http://yannickloriot.com/2014/02/cocoapods-and-the-localized-string-files/

But this is giving me a warning while installing my Pod as -

```
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `MyLibrary` from `../MyLibrary`
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (2.6.0)
Using CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout (0.9.2)
Installing MyLibrary 0.0.1 (was 0.0.1)
Using CorePlot (1.6)
Using FrameAccessor (2.0)
Using HKCircularProgressView (1.1.0)
Using OpenCV (2.4.9.2)
Using ViewDeck (2.3.1)
Generating Pods project
2015-08-20 15:31:39.478 ruby[31394:8637187] warning:  The file reference for 

"Base.lproj" 
is a member of multiple groups ("Capture" and "Slideshow"); this indicates a malformed 
project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership 
in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than 
one group, please add another reference to the same path.
2015-08-20 15:31:39.479 ruby[31394:8637187] warning:  The file reference for "de.lproj" 
is a member of multiple groups ("Capture" and "Slideshow"); this indicates a malformed 
project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in 
targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one 
group, please add another reference to the same path.
2015-08-20 15:31:39.479 ruby[31394:8637187] warning:  The file reference for "en.lproj" is 
a member of multiple groups ("Capture" and "Slideshow"); this indicates a malformed project.  
Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will 
be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please 
add another reference to the same path.
Integrating client project
Sending stats
```

**What I need**

1. How to deal with this error?
2. How can I use a pod which has localised xibs, so that when my sources and resources are installed they should be in the same format...?

Comment: Did you solve your error ?

Comment: Yes, Error is solved by Loegic's answer. But my second question is still a mystery.

Comment: OK so you can upvote the answer as well, for the scone question, could you detail a little more "they should be in the same format"

Comment: Doesn't resolve the issue for me. Seems like it didn't work for someone else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are importing the `Base.lproj` twice: in 
`s.resources = "MyLibrary/**/**/*.{png, lproj}"` and in `s.ios.resource_bundle = { 'CamerCaptureLibBundle-iOS' => ['**/**/*.lproj'] }`

You have to change the `s.resources` imports to exclude the `Base.lproj` file.

Comment: You don't have to specify s.ios.ressource if your project is only compatible with iOS. the error you are getting is because you import the lproj twice, remove completely the line s.ios.ressouvre in that case

Comment: What issue are you talking about, the first one, or the second ?

Comment: I see down votes, on a successful answer, without any explanation, what do you expect from me ?